# OCR library for reading fixed design documents

Tags: libraries, ocr

Is there any OCR-library/cliapp that lets me do something like this:

```
# ./ocrapp -input file.pdf -posx 3.6cm -posy 7.8cm -width 10cm -height 1.5cm -output rawdata.txt
```

I'm trying to automate reading of Customer ID numbers, sums and such from scanned invoices and bills. I'm looking for a library or a cli-app because I want to create my own document management system from it ;) (platform is not important, just not osx only).

A typical norwegian invoice looks like this: http://www.fakturo.no/img/uploads/WindowsLiveWriterHvordansenderderefakturaenppapir_1001Bfakturaeksempel_uten_logo_thumb_1.gif

The information I need to extract is in the bottom. (KID, Beløp and Kontonummer)

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you find a command line cropping tool e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/124692/command-line-tool-to-crop-pdf-files on ubuntu

You can then write a short script to crop each invoice into small sections which contain the text you want, and run those through any OCR program.

Of course, if you're writing a document management system, this could all be done using common libraries for your chosen programming language (and this question should probably be on stackoverflow)

Comment: I just did an actual facepalm, because I didn't think of doing it that way myself... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK. 
This is the link for detailed guide how to recognize text fields: [http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/text-fields](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/text-fields/?utm_source=https://superuser.com/&utm_medium=Comment&utm_campaign=SMM)
I work for ABBYY and if you need additional information I'm ready to help you.